# Kobo Desktop install problem

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, libraries

I'm trying to install Kobo Desktop reader in Ubuntu 16.04, but without success. I followed this topic also [How can I install Kobo Desktop on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338186/how-can-i-install-kobo-desktop-on-ubuntu)

I actually managed to install , but it does not run, I tried to run it in terminal but I get

```
/usr/local/Kobo/Kobo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Someone managed to install and run successfully?

If there is no longer the possibility of using it , there are some alternative software?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calibre ebook reader from the default Ubuntu repositories supports two types of Kobo ebook readers:

- Kobo Vox and Kobo Aura HD
- Kobo and Kobo Touch Readers

To access the below screen from Calibre, run the Calibre welcome wizard by selecting...
click downward black arrow next to *Preferences **▾*** -> select *Run welcome wizard* from the dropdown menu -> click through to the second screen of the Calibre welcome wizard.

[image]